# Is it possible to update managed package contents using Force.com Migration Tool (ANT Tool)

Tags: metadata-api, ant

Is it possible to update managed package contents like apex class/trigger of an installed instance of a package authored by another publisher using Ant Tool using deploy target? If then how to give the specified package which has to be updated?

Answer (score 3):

If by managed package you mean the installed instance of a package authored by another publisher, then no.

But if you mean the source code of a managed package that you own in a packaging org that you control, yes.

You can generate the package.xml by retrieving it by name. Or if it already exists in an unmanaged environment, you can add the following lines to it:

```
<apiAccessLevel>Unrestricted</apiAccessLevel>
<namespacePrefix>your_ns</namespacePrefix>
```

Then use a task like this to deploy into the packaging org:

```
<target name="push" description="Deploys all package components">
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com" deployRoot="src"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Do you have a hands on experiment?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @ShebinMathew - are you looking for the entirety of `package.xml` and `build.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check my [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181300/is-it-possible-to-update-and-upload-package-upon-code-commit-to-git).

Here is what I use to manage this.

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>DevMuza</fullName>
    <apiAccessLevel>Unrestricted</apiAccessLevel>
    <description>DevMuza Package to test CircleCI.</description>
    <namespacePrefix>dev_muza</namespacePrefix>
    <types>
        <members>ContactCounter_Ext</members>
        <members>ContactCounter_Ext_UT</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>CountContacts</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account.Number_of_Contacts__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>40.0</version>
</Package>
```

build.xml:

```
...
  <target name="updatePackage">
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="." singlePackage="true" />
  </target>
...
```